# Rounding issue with np.arange()

Tags: python, numpy, range, rounding

I created a list of numbers via `[i for i in np.arange(0.0,0.3,0.05)]`. This returned an unusual result:

```
[0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15000000000000002, 0.2, 0.25]
```

The args for `np.arange()` are `start`,`stop`, and `step`. With a `step` of 0.05 and a `start`/`stop` of 0.0 - 0.3, I would have expected an `arange` of

```
[0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25]
```

What is causing that odd 2e-18?

Comment: From the [doc](https://www.bing.com/search?form=MOZLBR&pc=MOZI&q=np.arange) *When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.*

Comment: Interestingly, even `np.linspace(0.0, 0.25, 6).tolist()` produces the same first output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken Simply try `.1 + .05 ` in python and it gives `0.15000000000000002` . Try - `list(np.arange(0.0,0.3,0.05).round(2))` if you want to round it off.